# Why we need the irvine library in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, irvine32

I need to know why we need to use this library in assembly lenguage, what is the importance?, please and thank you.

It's the first time that I saw this library and I don't understand the function.

Comment: Best I can tell from a quick look, this is a *convenience library* that lets assembly language programmers avoid the burden of creating their own input/output and string handling functionalitys. You can certainly program in assembly language without this library if you take on that work yourself.

Comment: The library itself is written in assembly. You can look in the source. There is nothing magical about it.